# GeoPandas write esri-shape file failure: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_file'

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, attributeerror

I've got a geodata-frame like this:

```
grid_up2geo.head()

Out[13]: 

   jahr  la3_id  ...  0                                           geometry
0  2000       1  ...  0  POLYGON ((2690000.000 4342000.000, 2690000.000...
1  2001       1  ...  1  POLYGON ((2690000.000 4342000.000, 2690000.000...
2  2002       1  ...  2  POLYGON ((2690000.000 4342000.000, 2690000.000...
3  2003       1  ...  3  POLYGON ((2690000.000 4342000.000, 2690000.000...
4  2004       1  ...  4  POLYGON ((2690000.000 4342000.000, 2690000.000...

[5 rows x 26 columns]
```

I want to save this as an esri-style shape file:

```
grid_up2geo.to_file('grid_up2geo.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

However, I get this error-code:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5274, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

    AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_file'
```

I imported fiona and wonder what I am doing wrong. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure it is a geodataframe and not just a dataframe? `type(grid_up2geo)`

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 8):

The error clearly states that `grid_up2geo` is not a GeoDataFrame, but DataFrame. You need to create a GeoDataFrame to be able to use `to_file` method. You can easily create a GeoDataFrame from a DataFrame using the following lines:

For >= v0.9.0:

```
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame, GeoSeries

# previous lines

# CRS looks like a UTM. Enter EPSG code of UTM here. For example 32637
crs_code = 32637

grid_up2geo['geometry'] = GeoSeries.from_wkt(grid_up2geo['geometry'])
grid_up2geo = GeoDataFrame(grid_up2geo, crs=crs_code)

grid_up2geo.to_file('grid_up2geo.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

For < 0.9.0:

```
from shapely import wkt

# previous lines

crs_code = 32637

grid_up2geo['geometry'] = grid_up2geo.geometry.apply(wkt.loads)
grid_up2geo = GeoDataFrame(grid_up2geo, crs=crs_code)

grid_up2geo.to_file('grid_up2geo.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```